# Different default date formats within flow

Tags: flow, date

I'm using a visual workflow. If I enter current date as the default value in a text field, then it will show up mm/dd/year. But if I put the date in a formula field I get year-mm-dd. 
Sometimes I am setting the date automatically, and sometimes I am making it part of a note, and the formats are saving differently.

**Does anyone know of a way to control which format without just separating out the particular elements into different parts of the formula?**

You can use thisthis formula to make the date show up in the year-mm-dd format but it requires the components to be split. It was a little annoying because using just the MONTH() would leave all months before October as 1 digit. Same with days.

```
TEXT(YEAR({!$Flow.CurrentDate}))
&"-"&
IF(LEN(TEXT(MONTH({!$Flow.CurrentDate})))<2,"0","")&TEXT(MONTH({!$Flow.CurrentDate}))
&"-"&
IF(LEN(TEXT(DAY({!$Flow.CurrentDate})))<2,"0","")&TEXT(DAY({!$Flow.CurrentDate}))
```